# Javascript short condition meaning

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

What does that js code means?

```
this.totals || (this.totals={});
```

i suppose..

```
if(!this.totals) {
  this.totals = {}
}
```

is this correct?

Comment: `if(typeof this.totals == "undefined") {` would be better. Because `false`/`0` may break the condition there.

Comment: Almost correct. The whole thing is an expression and also evaluates to (the new value of) `this.totals`.

Comment: @Thilo: Don't forget about semicolon at the end :-)

Answer (score 8):

You are *almost* 100% correct. When `||` is encountered the first part is evaluated and if it's a truthy value it is returned. If it's a falsey value the second part is evaluated which in this case sets `this.totals` to `{}` and returns the evaluation, `{}`.

Comment: Why only "*almost* 100%"?

Comment: Because unlike the `if` statement as Thilo pointed out in his comment, this is an expression so it returns a result. If you had `var a = this.totals || (this.totals = {})` `a` would equal `this.totals` as well. So the equivalent statement would be `if (!this.totals) { this.totals = {}; } var a = this.totals;`

Comment: But with the `;` at the end, it's an expression *statement* :-)

Comment: @Bergi True. But one could still put a `var a = ` in front of it.